# Create multiple JavaScript variables?

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript.  Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?  I have created an error message for an HTML form.  The name field works, but I want to create an individual message if other fields are left blank.

Below is my JavaScript code:

```
function validateForm() {
  var name = document.forms["contactform"]["name"].value;
  if (name == "")
    var email = document.forms["contactform"]["email"].value;
  if (name == "") {
    document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "Please enter your name";
    return false;
    document.getElementById('erroremail').innerHTML = "Please enter your email";
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you check `name` twice? (`if (name == "")`) Why are you returning *before* you change the content of `#erroremail`?

Comment: What is your issue really?

Comment: you returned twice, last two instructions are never reachable.

Comment: I want to create an error message in case a field is left blank for the name, email, and telephone number, for example.  How do I create individual variables?  The error message for my name field works, but won't work for anything else with my above JavaScript.  I did correct the duplicate 'name' in my if statement.

Comment: Ok. Why checking `(name == "")` twice? You'd stop at the first of the two `return`s. Rearrange your code a bit and you'll be just fine, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

1. Syntactically: 
   This code is not reached: `document.getElementById('erroremail').innerHTML = "Please enter your email";`

Put it before the first return and remove the second return.

```
if (name == "") {
document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "Please enter your name";
document.getElementById('erroremail').innerHTML = "Please enter your email";
return false;
}
```

2. Logically:

Why would you test twice the same exact thing?

Solution:

Test for empty email => do something

Test for empty name => do something

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you `return` something before checking another validation. When you return something, the function stops and nothing after return gets validated.

In your situation,you can declare a variable which is true by default `var ret=true;` and if a condition doesn't meet your requirements it becomes false.

For example:

```
function test() {
 var ret = true;
 if( 1 !== 1 ) {
  ret = false; //you will return false in the end
 }
 return ret; //return the result. from this point on, the function exits and doesn't do anything after
 alert("This will not be executed because there is a 'return' before");
}
```

The above function will return `false` and it will not execute the alert because you already return a result from that function

What you need is:

```
function validateForm() {
      var ret = true;
      var name = document.forms["contactform"]["name"].value;
      if (name == "") {
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "Please enter your name";
        ret = false;
      }
      var email = document.forms["contactform"]["email"].value;
      if (email== "") {
       document.getElementById('erroremail').innerHTML = "Please enter your email";
        ret = false;
      }
      return ret;
    }
```

Comment: Posting code without explanation is bad. Plus, this code will stop on the first error it finds.

Comment: This code actually worked.  Can you please explain what 'var ret = true;' is used for?

Comment: If you returned false when name was empty, then email wouldn't be verified anymore. This way both name and email are verified and you get both errors. In the end, you return true or false.

Comment: That makes sense.  What would I do if I wanted 3, 4, or 5 fields verified, for example?  Would I still have 1 'var ret = true;' for just the NAME?  Thank you.